# How do I find the longest strings in the array?

Tags: arrays, string, go

Actually I am able to get it done using two loops in Go Language, for example if I have array as:

```
["aa", "aab", "bcd", "a", "cdf", "bb"]
```

I need to return strings with maxLength. So output will be:

```
["aab", "bcd", "cdf"]
```

Here's what I am doing.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func allLongestStrings(inputArray []string) []string {
    maxLength := len(inputArray[0])
    outputArray := []string{}
    for _, value := range inputArray {
        if len(value) > maxLength {
            maxLength = len(value)
        }
    }
    for _, val := range inputArray {
        if len(val) == maxLength {
            outputArray = append(outputArray, val)
        }
    }
    return outputArray
}

func main() {
    xs := []string{"aa", "aab", "bcd", "a", "cdf", "bb"}
    fmt.Println(allLongestStrings(xs))
}
```

Is it possible to do this in one loop because I am running the same loop twice to find length and to append strings in outputArray.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
func allLongestStrings(inputArray []string) []string {
    max := -1 // -1 is guaranteed to be less than length of string
    var result []string
    for _, s := range inputArray {
        if len(s) < max {
            // Skip shorter string
            continue
        }
        if len(s) > max {
            // Found longer string. Update max and reset result.
            max = len(s)
            result = result[:0]
        }
        // Add to result
        result = append(result, s)
    }
    return result
}
```

As peterSO points out in another answer, the result slice can have a capacity larger than required and can contain string values past the length of slice. The extra allocation and string references may be a problem in some contexts (result is retained for a long time, strings are large, ...). Return a [copy of the slice](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks#copy) if the allocation and references are a concern.

```
func allLongestStrings(inputArray []string) []string {
    ...
    return append([]string(nil), result...)
}
```

If the function can mutate the original slice, then the function result can be constructed in the input slice. This avoids the allocation of the result slice.

```
func allLongestStrings(inputArray []string) []string {
    n := 0
    max := -1
    for i, s := range inputArray {
        if len(s) < max {
            // Skip shorter string
            continue
        }
        if len(s) > max {
            // Found longer string. Update max and reset result.
            max = len(s)
            n = 0
        }
        inputArray[n], inputArray[i] = inputArray[i], inputArray[n]
        n++
    }
    return inputArray[:n]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do it by using the sort package. Basically, what you do is to create a custom sort function by implementing [sort.Interface](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Interface) and use [sort.Sort](https://golang.org/pkg/sort/#Sort) to your advantage.

```
package main

import "sort"
import "fmt"

type sortByLength []string

// Len implements Len of sort.Interface
func (s sortByLength) Len() int {
   return len(s)
}

// Swap implements Swap of sort.Interface
func (s sortByLength) Swap(i, j int) {
   s[i], s[j] = s[j], s[i]
}

// Less implements Less of sort.Interface
func (s sortByLength) Less(i, j int) bool {
    return len(s[i]) > len(s[j])
}

func main() {
    toFind := []string{"aa", "aab", "bcd", "a", "cdf", "bb"}

    // We sort it by length, descending
    sort.Sort(sortByLength(toFind))

    // The first element is sure to be the longest
    longest := []string{toFind[0]}

    // In case we have more than one element in toFind...
    if len(toFind) > 1 {

        // ...we need to find all remaining elements of toFind...
        for _, str := range toFind[1:] {

            // ...which are not smaller than the first element of longest.
            if len(str) < len(longest[0]) {

                // In case the current element is smaller in length, we can stop iterating
                // over toFind.
                break
            }

            // We know that str has the same length as longest[0], so we append it
            longest = append(longest, str)

        }
    }
    fmt.Println(longest)
}
```

**<kbd>[Run it on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/q53E3YAulW-)</kbd>**

However, while only having one loop in your own code, the sorting obviously iterates over the input, too.

Comment: Sorting modifies the original slice and loops internally. In any case, the sort approach can use a prefix of the sorted slice instead of creating a new result slice.  https://play.golang.org/p/QJQmWlp7rSp

Comment: All valid points. I will modify the answer accordingly. However, it was not explicitly stated that the original slice needs to be unchanged.